# How to use multiple github accounts with hub?

Tags: git, github, authorization, accounts

I have main account with ssh. For testing reason I created another github account and trying to create repository with `hub`

```
hub create anotherAccount/SomeRepo
```

But I have

```
Error creating repository: Not Found (HTTP 404)
```

I would like to be able to manage multiple accounts' repositories via hub. What is the way to do that?